# Tricky angularjs situation. Cannot see scope values in html

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

Hi I'm having a strange problem. I'm not able to plunker it, so I will just try to explain and maybe someone has had the same problem or can give me a hint to where to search.

I've been setting up an angular app with some tests in webstorm. I only test services. Then, when I wanted to build the html layer on top, I can't get the html to bind with the controllers. I don't get any errors in the console, the routing works, text in the html file is displayed, and "console.logs" in the controller prints out all scope values correctly. Even custom directives work and the passing of attribute values to them.

However, all databindings in the html do not work. Wherever {{name}} and such is in the html file, nothing is displayed. The same goes for directives. Even though the "console.log(scope)" in the directive shows that the attributes have been set correctly.
Another strange thing is that I cannot write in input fields.

I really have no clue as I've checked every thing I could think of. I'm using webstorm 7.0, AngularJS v1.2.0rc1 and I'm using the "open in browser" in Webstorm.

This is working in other projects I'm making, so I'm really wondering what's going on here.

Comment: Have you verified that scopes are correct? I.e. that the bound variables do exist in the correct scope. There may be scope nesting & transclusions situations that are tricky. Check the scopes with Batarang or [this nice plugin](https://github.com/kosprov/AngScope) for Firefox.

Comment: They do exist and even if I simplify html/ controllers to ONLY contain Hey {{name}} in html and controller only has $scope.name = 'James', only "Hey" is displayed. However, I do have console.log($scope) in the controller and can clearly see that name is a proper variable. That's why I think there is something else which I can't find. Also this, that I cannot write in an input field although I don't have any directives preventing me, puzzles me.